# Global CBT Hook in Windows 7 fails eventually

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, hook, global

I am using a global CBT hook setup to stop new windows from stealing focus. I am injecting the c++ DLL from a c# app. It functions fine for a while and then stops working. I thought it might be timing out, but I changed my LowLevelHooksTimeout in my registry and rebooted. That didn't help.

I am not that great with c++. So, perhaps it is an error in my code. What could be causing it to fail? Also, is there a way to deal with the name mangling and clean up that code a bit?

WindowMonitor.cpp

```
   #include <map>
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include "header.h"
   using namespace std;

   #pragma data_seg(".TEST")
   HHOOK hook=0;
   #pragma data_seg()
   #pragma comment(linker, "/section:.TEST,rws")

   extern "C"
    {
   __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
        {
    if (nCode<=0)  return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    if (nCode==HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        try {
            CBTACTIVATESTRUCT* stuff=(CBTACTIVATESTRUCT*) lParam;

            if (stuff!=0)
            {
            if (stuff->fMouse==TRUE)
            {

                return 0;
            }
            if (stuff->fMouse==FALSE)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            }
        }
        catch (exception& e)
        {

        }

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                  DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                  LPVOID lpReserved
                  )
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

    break;
}
return TRUE;
}

bool InjectCBTHook()
{

HMODULE hDll;
HOOKPROC cbtProcAddr;
DWORD proc_id;


hDll        = LoadLibraryA("WindowMonitor.dll");
cbtProcAddr = (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hDll, "_CBTProc@12"); 

hook=SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, cbtProcAddr, hDll, 0);

if (hook==0) 
{
    int x=GetLastError();
    return FALSE;
}

return TRUE;
}

bool EjectCBTHooks()
{
 UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
 return TRUE;
 }
```

WindowMonitor.h

```
#ifndef WM
#define WM
extern "C" {

#define DLLEXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)
  DLLEXPORT bool InjectCBTHook() ;
  DLLEXPORT bool EjectCBTHooks();
}

#endif
```

C# P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("WindowMonitor.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool InjectCBTHook();
[DllImport("WindowMonitor.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool EjectCBTHooks();
```

Comment: unrelated: I applaud your idea; commenting to remember to check this back or devise a similar dll myself!

Comment: CBT hooks have a couple problems. You can probably use what is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx) to do this better.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the events with SetWinEventHook?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to use SetWinEventHook for what I want.